# What unit testing tools should I use for Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

I'm starting up a brand new project using VS2010 and Silverlight 4.  This is my first Silverlight project and I'm at a loss as to what tools I should use for both mocking and unit testing.  There's Rhino.Mocks 3.5 for Silverlight, but the author marked it as an [alpha release](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/02/04/rhino-mocks-3.5-ndash-silverlight.aspx).  Moq claims Silverlight support, but I've not used it before.  As far as unit testing, there are a few options, but a lot of the information out there seems a bit dated.

So what are the best unit testing tools to use on a new Silverlight 4 project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Nunit, [Silverlight Unit Testing Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut)
, [StatLigt](http://statlight.codeplex.com/) for unit testing.

For mocking try moq. It is linq to mocks.

Comment: Could you help me with that ? I can not figure it out how to run NUnit + Moq + SL in one package. Do you have any tutorial ? Any links ?

Comment: @Jasper what do you mean by 'it out how to run NUnit + Moq + SL in one package'

Comment: As I understand Silverlight framework it's not the same as regular .NET Framework. So - how do you load/NUnit test SL project from inside of regular .NET project - or otherwise - where do you find NUnit + console runner (??) + Rhino mocks (SL version ?) and keep all SL reference (for example System.Windows.dll) intact ? The idea - I just want to test the code not the GUI